# Apply "assertTrue" unit testing to pandas DataFrame?

Tags: python, pandas, unit-testing, python-unittest

Using unit testing of python, how can I check that the column names of pandas DataFrame `df` coincide with column names of the list?

```
import unittest

column_names_list = ["col1","col2","col3"]

assertTrue(df.columns in column_names_list)
```

For example, I should get False for this `df`:

```
col1   col2   col3   col4
aasa   4546   5643   shsh
...
```

Comment: `sorted(list(set(df.columns) & set(column_names_list)))==column_names_list` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using `set` you can find the difference between two lists and `assert` that it's 0

```
In [40]: assert len(set(df.columns) - set(['A', 'B', 'C'])) == 0

In [41]: assert len(set(df.columns) - set(['A', 'B', 'D'])) == 0
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AssertionError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
----> 1 assert len(set(df.columns) - set(['A', 'B', 'D'])) == 0
```

Comment: Will it check the names? No only number of columns?

Comment: I get `IndentationError: unexpected indent` next to `assert`. I use Python 2.7.

Comment: I am also, you must be introducing a garbage character or unintended space/tab. As for `set`, read more about it [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/sets.html). By using `set`, we can write a unit test that asserts that neither list of columns has an element that isn't in the other. The order doesn't matter. Lists aren't hashable so you won't be able to use the `in` keyword from your example.

Comment: Note: This doesn't raise an AssertionError if one of the columns is missing. It only triggers if there are other, not expected columns in the DataFrame. e.g. {'A', 'B'} - {'A', 'B', 'C'} == {}

Comment: @de1 Very true. It might be better to use `set.difference()` then: `assert len(set(df.columns).difference(set(['A', 'B', 'C', 'D']))) == 0`

Comment: @AlexS but what is the advantage of comparing the length of a difference set over just comparing the two sets?

Answer (score 1):

You can also use equality of sets. That way an assertion error may be more helpful (using curly brackets for sets):

## matching

```
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['col1', 'col2', 'col3'])
assert set(df.columns) == {'col1', 'col2', 'col3'}
```

## not matching

```
df = pd.DataFrame([], columns=['col1', 'col2'])
assert set(df.columns) == {'col1', 'col2', 'col3'}
```